# How to pull an online GitHub repository every night via CRON?

Tags: git, github, freebsd, caddy

I have a local web server on my NAS inside my home, with a small VM running Caddy's webserver.  I have cloned the repository https://github.com/openspeedtest/Speed-Test to a local folder (/usr/local/www/Speed-Test), and configured Caddy to serve up that folder as a website - so far, so good.  I can access the site and test speeds on my LAN without issue.

I'd like to set up a CRON job to pull from that web repository on a nightly basis, and pull down the current files, replacing the existing local ones.  Because it's only a bunch of static HTML files, there's no need to configure anything local, and I'll automatically get the latest updates without needing to manually pull them.

I did search online, but most of the results I am looking for involve merging existing changes or such.  I'm just looking to overwrite the existing folder with the current repository, and I can't seem to find the code / arguments to do this.

Thank you!

Comment: Note that on Unix, BSD--and Linux, too--they are "directories" and not the Windows graphical concept of "folders" which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to have a local one-way mirror you can put the following into a script that is invoked by cron

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "--random-delay" ]
then
        sleep $(awk "BEGIN { srand(); print rand()*$2*60 }")
fi

cd /usr/local/www/Speed-Test
git checkout main
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/main
```

It will discard any local commits and modifications and reset the files to match the latest content of the `main` branch of the remote repository.

If you put an entry into crontab on a specific time (as opposed to adding a script to `/etc/cron.daily`), it is nice to add a bit of randomness into when the script runs (e.g. to avoid that "everyone" starts pulling from github at exactly 1:00 at night for instance) which you can do by invoking it as `/some/where/update-speed-test.sh --random-delay 20` for instance.

Comment: Note: he's usingi FreeBSD where bash is not a native shell and potentially isn't used.

Comment: The only bash specific thing in the script is the `$(...)` construct (although I think that is actually a posix feature), but in worst case they can be replaced with backtics.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, about an hour after I posted this, I thought of a solution - use a script called by CRON, instead of just a command:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/www/Speed-Test/*

rm -rf /usr/local/www/Speed-Test/.*

git clone https://github.com/openspeedtest/Speed-Test /usr/local/www/Speed-Test
```

I set that up last night, and confirmed it worked as intended this morning.